# using map to create shortcut in gvim doesn't work

Tags: vim

I've added the following line to my .gvimrc file:

```
map <F3> /[1-9]
```

I want F3 key to search for any sequence in the form of (1 Error, 3 Errors....).

For some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: when i press F3 inside the gvim editor it doesn't search and point to the first location of '1 error'.

Answer (score 1):

you need a Enter at the end of your mapping:

```
nnoremap <F3> /[1-9] <cr>
```

This will search for a single digit (1-9) and with a space followed.